# SP2010 Install on virtual

Tags: active-directory, installation, sql-server, setup

I started to work on a home based play project where I wanted to created at least 2 VM (using vmware). Server 2k8 went good. then I moved on to setup AD (DC) and completed this piece. next step was to install sql server 2k8 r2 but keep getting access denied error (looked at the sql log and learned the some account dont have access hklm but I am logged in with admin account and admin is a domain account). Went through these setup steps per Andrew connell's (from criticalpath) pdf. Per his instruction, Everything (AD, SQL 2k8 r2, sp2010) is residing on one server.

Ideally, I would like to create extremely thin AD VM, a SQL VM and a SP2010 VM. I could not find any article that walks me through this.

I started a AD box on VM but my other VM machine dont see this VM when I try to add the 2nd VM to the Domain. I may be missing something (like setting static IP address for AD VM).

Is there a good article (yes, i did google but not finding) that can walk me through this....

Thanks

Comment: As @JesusShelby mentions, this question is off topic. You may want to ask your server related questions on http://serverfault.com/.. however, you will need to ask a more specific question. Perhaps focus on the particular access denied issue?

Comment: @KitMenke: Thanks Kit. I never heard serverfault before but now I do. so I will be using that site. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't really the place for these types of questions.  The [FAQ](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq) has some more detail on how to determine if this is the right 'place' for your question.

Most of your server related questions (AD , VMware) could be asked on [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/search?q=vmware), however, you will probably want to visit the [VMware Forums](http://communities.vmware.com/index.jspa) regarding your networking configuration question.

SharePoint installation is covered on [TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262957.aspx) in detail (including some video walk thrus), and the install is the same whether you install via dedicated hardware or virtual, the differences lie in the configuration of the supporting platform.

Should add, that you could always utilize the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/) as well.

I was to long winded to post in the comments section :)